# How to reproduce a diagram with plotted random data

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

How to set this blue line to be like on this picture?[image]

This is my code, I tried to change samples from 90 to 130 but didn't work.

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]

\begin{axis}

[xlabel=$t$,ylabel=$x(t)$,xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-2,ymax=2,grid=major,grid style={solid}]
\addplot[roza,line width=1pt,smooth] expression{(sin(90*x))+0.5};
\addplot[domain=-5:5,blue,samples=126,line width=0.7pt] expression{sin(90*x)+0.4*rand};
\addplot[roza,line width=1pt, smooth]expression{(sin(90*x))-0.5};


\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is what looks like :

[image]

Comment: Welcome! I do not understand your question. When I embed your fragment in an appropriate document I can change the number of samples to 130 without problems. I also do not understand why you think that this will make the plot look like the first one. The more important change is probably to find some appropriate value for `\pgfmathsetseed`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that samples didn't work, I thought that will help me to look like the first one. I didn't understand what I need to change to get the blue line like on the first photo ?

Comment: Unless you have the precise code that produced it and the author set `\pgfmathsetseed{...}` explicitly it won't be very easy to reproduce it with LaTeX methods since this seems to be a random plot. You can use computer algebra systems like Mathematica to extract the coordinates.

Comment: I don't understand.  You have a squiggly blue line between two sinusoidal red lines.  How are you saying they're different?  I will grant that the lines in the first plot are thicker and darker, but that doesn't seem to be your complaint.

Answer (score 3):

A reproduction of the posted image is as follows.

[image]

As it can be seen in the code, the followed approach is to plot data points that have been extracted from the original image.
Therefore, it is more of a gimmick in the reproduction of the random data sequence than what it should be (will we ever know?).
But, as I stated at first, this is intended as a *reproduction* (that is, a copy).

Scroll to the end of the MWE for the relevant part.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{filecontents}{rand.dat}
-4.98603821481  -1.15447154472
-4.91715550067  -1.31707317073
-4.82165277349  -0.634146341463
-4.68182909677  -1.20325203252
-4.58536585366  -0.634146341463
-4.48053240026  -1.05691056911
-4.38626462214  -0.227642276423
-4.28101951906  -0.69918699187
-4.18057699564  -0.60162601626
-3.98284792975  -0.0325203252033
-3.92055161058  0.585365853659
-3.78292339885  0.276422764228
-3.68124592638  0.227642276423
-3.61840074097  0.780487804878
-3.51946759974  1.05691056911
-3.41833899352  1.07317073171
-3.31309389043  0.60162601626
-3.21800281294  1.33333333333
-3.08353058214  1.39837398374
-3.01176632019  0.894308943089
-2.90953998148  0.780487804878
-2.77575383349  0.926829268293
-2.67503687695  0.991869918699
-2.57171280574  0.747967479675
-2.50420225721  0.747967479675
-2.37110219203  0.975609756098
-2.2971424651  0.211382113821
-2.196288292  0.260162601626
-2.09447360296  0.19512195122
-1.85201193784  -0.536585365854
-1.78724572056  -0.211382113821
-1.65044080821  -0.422764227642
-1.57799046345  -1.0081300813
-1.4451648314  -0.747967479675
-1.34335014236  -0.813008130081
-1.17086892388  -1.25203252033
-1.0713869164  -1.0406504065
-0.933484271552  -1.38211382114
-0.866385372714  -1.33333333333
-0.769922129601  -0.764227642276
-0.632431134438  -1.05691056911
-0.470241158108  -0.276422764228
-0.334122328565  -0.406504065041
-0.168639154746  -0.0162601626016
-0.0340297073857  0.0325203252033
0.0363623889403  -0.308943089431
0.168639154746  0.0162601626016
0.231347123598  0.585365853659
0.365133271586  0.731707317073
0.466536310933  0.715447154472
0.566567184659  0.861788617886
0.637233714109  0.487804878049
0.732324791602  1.21951219512
0.872285684882  0.634146341463
1.03475009434  1.38211382114
1.13944633117  0.975609756098
1.27336969572  1.10569105691
1.34595725704  0.50406504065
1.47905732222  0.731707317073
1.58100922781  0.650406504065
1.65044080821  0.422764227642
1.78367808995  0.634146341463
1.88604164523  0.50406504065
1.9598641556  -0.243902439024
2.09392473672  -0.130081300813
2.19766045762  -0.422764227642
2.29851463072  -0.373983739837
2.3997804535  -0.373983739837
2.47181914857  -0.910569105691
2.60409591438  -0.585365853659
2.70440122123  -0.471544715447
2.77753764879  -1.13821138211
2.87523584097  -0.715447154472
2.97801104593  -0.894308943089
3.07913965216  -0.878048780488
3.17848444307  -0.650406504065
3.28043634867  -0.731707317073
3.38376041988  -0.975609756098
3.51878151693  -0.975609756098
3.58519433296  -0.845528455285
3.6808342767  -0.178861788618
3.78621659634  -0.666666666667
3.95211141985  -0.325203252033
4.08342766972  0.113821138211
4.18551679188  0.0162601626016
4.28225446811  0.552845528455
4.38502967308  0.373983739837
4.51922747076  0.471544715447
4.61816061199  0.747967479675
4.72011251758  0.666666666667
4.78254605331  1.26829268293
4.91701828411  1.33333333333
4.98741038043  0.991869918699
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        xlabel=$t$,
        ylabel=$x(t)$,
        xmin=-5,
        xmax=5,
        ymin=-2,
        ymax=2,
        grid=major,
        grid style={solid},
        samples=75
    ]
    \addplot[red,line width=1pt,smooth] expression{(sin(90*x))+0.5};
    \addplot[red,line width=1pt, smooth]expression{(sin(90*x))-0.5};
    \addplot[blue,line width=0.7pt] table {rand.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how did you extract the data?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I don't know what Alessandro used, but I know of https://github.com/markummitchell/engauge-digitizer and https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/ for these tasks.

Comment: I used g3data. I think that it is no longer maintained by its original developer, but it is still included in most linux distributions
https://physics.carleton.ca/computing/unix-information/application-documentation/g3data

Comment: Thanks @HenriMenke! Looks like engauge-digitizer is more actively maintained than g3data :)

Comment: That is commitment to reproduce the original picture pushed to the limit ^^